# Use argument as variable name (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I can't seem to find a question that answers this directly.

I'd like to use a function argument as the name of a variable within that function.

e.g.,

```
test(var1);

function test(foo)
{
    var foo = 'Hello world!'; // Set var1
}

alert(var1); // Hello world!
```

Can I use the brackets here (i.e., window.[ ])?

Comment: you mean your variable contains a bracket? or you mean array?

Comment: Don't think in terms of variables. Think of terms in properties (and how they relate to Maps/Dictionaries/Objects) - properties can have arbitrary string names and can accessed as `obj[propNameExpression]`. Then consider that `window` evaluates to an Object and thus supports properties and normal property access (although some DOM/browser properties are "reserved"). That being said, using `window[prop]`, for an unconstrained prop value, is probably questionable. Consider `myObject[prop]` instead. You'll also need to pass in `"var1"` as a *string value* (or the identifier will be evaluated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, you can use brackets:

```
window[foo] = "Hello World"
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp6LY/)

Answer (score 1):

Er...okay, so this is almost certainly not a good idea.

Short answer: sorta. If you're running in a browser, you can do this:

```
var polluteGlobalNamespace = function(symbol) {
    window[symbol] = "whatever";
};
polluteGlobalNamespace('foo');
console.log(foo);
```

But that only works for global variables. There is no way to do this with function-scoped variables, because JavaScript lacks first class environments.

But unless you're doing some deep dark metaprogramming, this isn't a good idea. It might be better to post the problem that you're trying to solve with this function to see what the idiomatic way to do it is.